# how does bitcoin know which one is utxo?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, bitcoind

Let's say John gave 5 BTC to me. So, John took his unspent outputs and put it into inputs to create a transaction.  Let's say John already had a transaction which was holding exactly that amount of BTC.

Now, How can John not spend 5 BTC anymore ?  The output John used to give me 5BTC is still on Blockchain. So, does node go to that output transaction and mark it as spent ? how does it mark it as spent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the title, utxos are entirely consumed and refered in transactions inputs.

> Now, How can John not spend 5 BTC anymore ?

As long as the transaction spending it is in the most PoW block chain, no.

> The output John used to give me 5BTC is still on Blockchain. So, does node go to that output transaction and mark it as spent ?

If a valid transaction consumes it in a next block, it is marked as spent and not available anymore.

> how does it mark it as spent?

By updating a database commonly refered to as "the utxo set" in which are recorded not-yet-spent UTXOs. See [How is a Transaction Output Marked as Spent?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/28225/how-is-a-transaction-output-marked-as-spent/28260#28260) .

You likely want to give a look to questions regarding coin referencing and consumption by transactions, for example:

- [How is the UTXOs of each partially-spent TxIn determined?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/99078/how-is-the-utxos-of-each-partially-spent-txin-determined)
- [Why is there "Change" in Bitcoins?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/96822/why-is-there-change-in-bitcoins)